# Where should I define CommandBindings(InputBindings?

Tags: wpf, xaml, commandbinding

When using a `RoutedUiCommand` (e.g. for a button) I have to add the command to `CommandBindings` for them to be fully integrated. As far as I could determine, I can do this on one of the buttons ancestor elements.

What difference does it make, which ancestor I choose for adding the command to its `CommandBindings`? I see that WPF calls `CanExecute` after certain UI events (e.g. focus changed); does the location of the `CommandBindings` maybe influence the "scope" of which UI events trigger the `CanExecute` calls?

I intend to add the commands programmatically using a `ValueConverter`, i.e. the `RoutedUiCommand` of the button will be determined using a custom CommandConverter that should also add the resulting `RoutedUiCommand` to `CommandBindings`. Starting at the button element I can find any ancestor (in the visual tree) - which should I choose when?

**EDIT**: The same question applies to `InputBinding`. Does the element to which I add an `InputBinding` have an impact, i.e. scope in which the keyboard short cuts (gestures) are detected/processed?

Comment: *"for them to be fully integrated"* - not sure what that exactly means. If a Button's Command property has a Binding with a Converter, that Converter may just return an ICommand. No need to add it to any CommandBindings.

Comment: @Clemens: But what about CanExecute etc?

Comment: That's implemented by the ICommand property in the view model. Search the web for `RelayCommand`, an ICommand implementation.